# I have an error with pod install Kanna

Tags: ios, swift, podfile

[Screen my Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol6K3.png)

Whats the problem with my podfile?

I add it to my Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.1.0'
```

P.S. JSON and Alamofire works are excellent!

The console output from cocoapods reads:

```
Analyzing dependencies    
[!] The dependency `Kanna (~> 1.1.0)` is not used in any concrete target.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  For as trivial a piece of output as that image shows, you should definitely include the text in the question, not make people go to the image file.  It appears that you don't have anything that actually says it uses Kanna — more than that, I can't say since I've no idea of the larger context of the problem.  At the moment, I think there isn't enough information for anyone to be able to help you, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Post your complete `podfile`.

Comment: pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `Kanna (~> 1.1.0)` is not used in any concrete target.

Comment: use_frameworks!
pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.1.0' 
This is my podfile 
https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Comment: I've edited your question to include the console output - in future try to put this info in the question as often answerers don't read all the comments.  As @Dershowitz123 said could you edit your question to include the complete contents of your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your podfile I'm only really guessing here, but from my experience that error means that your podfile isn't formatted correctly.  Recently they made some changes to the podfile structure so if you have an old podfile but updated Cocoapods to a new version it is likely that your podfile won't work.

Everything in the podfile now needs to be explicitly attached to a target by placing it in that target's block.  If you run `pod init` the podfile generated should have a couple of blocks that look like this:

```
Target 'Your App' do

end
```

You may also have targets for `Your App iOSTests` and `Your App iOSUITests`.  If you open Xcode you'll see these targets correspond to the top-level folders in your project.

You'll want to place the `pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.1.0'` between the `Target` and `end` to attach it to that specific target.

If you have an old podfile without these targets I would recommend starting again with a fresh one generated by running `pod init`, though if you want you could reformat it to be in the above format.

Comment: I've just noticed you've placed `pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.1.0'` directly after `use_frameworks!` so I would suggest that this is the problem.